# Insurance Policy Probability

Tags: probability

Under an insurance policy, a maximum of five claims may be filed per year by a policyholder. Let $p_n$ be the probability that a policyholder files *n* claims during a given year, where *n*=0,1,2,3,4,5. An actuary makes the following observations:

i) $p_n$ ≥ $p_{n+1}$ for *n*=0,1,2,3,4.

ii) The difference between *$p_n$* and *$p_{n+1}$* is the same for n=0,1,2,3,4.

iii) Exactly 40% of policyholders file fewer than two claims during a given year.

Calculate the probability that a random policyholder will file more than three claims during a given year.

[image: 8A]

The textbook answer is above. I understand everything except for the part underlined in red. Please excuse my less than run of the mill paint skills. Anyway, 
we have $p_n-p_{n+1}$= *t*. Some common difference. Doesn't that mean $p_0-p_1$= *t*, $p_1-p_2$= *t*, etc.?

If this is the case, then how does $p_1 = p_0$+ *t*? Shouldn't $p_1 = p_0$- *t*? I understand that *t* is the common difference, so it's basically $p_0-p_1$ **or** $p_1-p_0$. However, something is wrong with my logic, because when I use $p_1-p_0$ instead of $p_0-p_1$, I clearly come to a different answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, $t$ is *negative* in the textbook answer (they find that $t = -\frac{1}{60}$), so it is still true that $p_{n+1}\le p_n$.

Of course, you would be correct if you used a positive value of $t$ and used $p_1 = p_0 - t$, $p_2 = p_1 - t$, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't catch that.